# navigation_mode_tabs vertical is not working

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I´m using the ActionBar

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

And Horizontal mode is working perfectly, but in vertical the separate bar (known as the "stacked action bar") is not working and its behavior is like `NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal and not a bug, if you were wondering. Reference [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24439) discussion on the Google code forums. Unfortunately you can't do something against it.